# Assign first page in Oracle APEX 5 based on login

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm currently building a recruiting application to replace one currently in use.

I want to be able to set the first page a user sees based on login. I'm currently using Application Express Authentication, but I also have a logins table that contains office, user name and user type, so when the user name in :APP_USER. matches the user name in the login table, it will pull the user type.

So if a recruiter logs in I want them to go to page 1, which is a recruiting dashboard, but if a salesmen logs in I want them to go to page 20, which is a sales dashboard.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to create custom auth to achieve what you want did you try that ?

Comment: I do actually, the logins table contains all the authentication info, I just need to find a way to get the login page to direct the user to the proper start page in the app based on the login type define in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I don't like altering the login mechanism. I certainly don't like performing code based on the username before the user has actually authenticated. The example by @trent isn't quite that yet since it has no actual selects, but I've seen people performing selects based on the username in order to retrieve some defaults or settings, only to be able to adjust the `p_app_page` parameter.

Those parameters will -not- always redirect to the page's you want unless you have deep linking disabled. With deep linking enabled the user will always go to his requested page, not the one provided in `p_app_page`. It's up to you to determine how the application should behave. Respect deep links or always redirect to a certain page?

Personally I prefer putting the redirect in the authentication scheme's post-authentication. **In my opinion** getting or setting user settings has no place on the login-page processes nor in the authentication code (it's meant to authenticate, not manipulate).

In the post-auth code I'd put the select on type and alter `FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL`. Note though that this will completely disregard deep links. You can leave the `ELSE` out, but that'll only retain deep links for non-sales and recruiters, as they will always land on their dashboard page.

```
DECLARE
  l_type persons.person_type%TYPE;
  l_url VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT person_type
    INTO l_type
    FROM persons
   WHERE username = :P101_USERNAME;

  l_url := 
  CASE l_type
  WHEN 'SALES' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':SALES_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  WHEN 'RECRUITER' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':RECRUITER_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  ELSE  -- go to home page
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':HOME:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  END;

  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL', l_url); 
END;
```

Comment: I think that's going to work! I won't be able to test until I get other parts of the app built.

Quick Question though, where the code says ':RECRUITER_DASH:', should I assign the recruiter dash page that page alias or just use the actual page number?

Comment: @greg That's up to you - it's the same thing. I've used an alias here for readability, and not having to "hardcode" the ID is something I prefer in these case. You never know if the "SALES_DASH" suddenly has to change. With an alias you're safer. But other than that, if you prefer the page id, it'll work just the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll use the Page Aliases as you recommend. This really helps a lot!

Comment: Alright, I'm at the point where I can implement this in the application, only problem is that I can't create a procedure since it can't handle the :P101_USERNAME variable and I can't add it into the custom_auth scheme since it chokes there as well when I add it to the PL/SQL.

I'm using APEX 5.1, where am I screwing this up?

Comment: Never mind Tom, I figured out where I was screwing up. When you add the code you have to define it and then add it to the post authentication procedure name.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of approaches.

If you have deep linking disabled (always go to a particular page), you can create a before header process to apply the redirection ([owa_util.redirect_url](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/w_util.htm#ARPLS70783) or [apex_util.redirect_url](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#AEAPI2324)).

Other examples I've seen usually involved clearing the session item `FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL`, and then using apex_custom_auth.login (in your login page process), as per:

```
declare
    l_to_page_num NUMBER;

begin

    if upper(:P101_USERNAME) = 'TRENT'
    then
        l_to_page_num := 2;
    else
        l_to_page_num := 1;
    end if;

    apex_util.set_session_State ('FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL', NULL);

    apex_custom_auth.login(
        p_uname => :P101_USERNAME,
        p_password => :P101_PASSWORD,
        p_app_page => :APP_ID || ':' || l_to_page_num);

end;
```

Source: https://community.oracle.com/message/10286176#10286176

Answer (score 1):

I personally like using branches on load within the home page, which can be ordered as appropriate, with associated authorisation schemes or condition.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that is looking to accomplish this, Tom had the perfect solution, here's how you put it into you custom authentication scheme.

When you edit the scheme, in the PL/SQL Code box enter your code so it looks like this

```
PROCEDURE post_authentication IS
BEGIN
DECLARE
  l_type logins.login_type%TYPE;
  l_url VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT login_type
    INTO l_type
    FROM logins
   WHERE upper(:P101_USERNAME) = USERNAME;

  l_url := 
  CASE l_type
  WHEN 'Sales' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':SALES_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  WHEN 'Recruiter' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':RECRUITER_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  WHEN 'Regional' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':REGIONAL_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  WHEN 'Admin' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':ADMIN_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  WHEN 'National' THEN
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':NATIONAL_DASH:' || V('APP_SESSION') 
  ELSE  -- go to home page
    'f?p=' || V('APP_ALIAS') || ':HOME:' || V('APP_SESSION')
  END;

  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL', l_url); 
END;
END post_authentication;
```

Then below in the in the **Post-Authentication Procedure Name** field under **Login Processing** make sure you put `post-Authentication` or what ever you decided to name the procedure on the PL/SQL box.

This will allow you redirect users based on user type if you're using a custom login table.